# What kind of database server should I use for a 500k stored procedure calls per day database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database, amazon-ec2, database-performance, stored-procedures

I have a database that gets about 500,000 stored procedure calls a day in addition to other stuff. It's running too slow for us and we're going to upgrade it when we get around to it.

I'm looking at Amazon EC2 as a solution and it seems alright. Sites like Reddit use it for extensive database stuff and they say good things about it. Are there any better solutions than Amazon EC2?

Comment: Read reddit's post carefully. Its phrased in a positive tone, but the actual details are that they had to jump through a bunch of hoops just to get mediocre levels of i/o performance. Hoops i'm not even sure are an option in windows (can you do software raid10 ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*No one else will know the answer to this question better then yourself!*

I would do some investigation into where the bottlenecks are on your current server. i.e. CPU, memory, disk i/o and use that to at least guesstimate the kind of specs you would need for a new database server + allowing for future growth & headroom.

Once you get your hands on the VPS from your educated guess you can then setup sql and run some testing, even something simple like a replaying a profiler trace & see how the server performance statistics compare to your current server.  These results will then allow you to improve/adjust your initial guess.

Answer (score 2):

Do you specifically want a 'cloudy' solution or is that just one option you're looking at?

It's actually only about 6sp/s - which isn't much but it all depends on what kind of load they place on the server - if they're very write-heavy then you're going to need to significantly bolster your storage performance, if they're very read-heavy then moving to a newer server (such as a nehalem xeon-based box) would really help as their memory is very fast.

Comment: make that 18/second (triple average as peak). Without knowing more, this can not be answered. I have a smaller server happily handling about 50 times that amount, without extreme load, but it is a small sp.